# Swift - AddressBook unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i'm trying to reference to the current address book as follow:

```
let addressBookRef: ABAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()
```

but i get an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values" by xCode.

I also tried to unwrap it doing:

```
if let addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil) {
    addressBook = addressBook.takeRetainedValue()
}
```

but I get an error, where am I wrong?

**SOLUTION**

```
let addressBookRef: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil)?.takeRetainedValue()
```

Comment: Did you check permission to access contacts?

Comment: @DipenPatel: yes i did

Comment: Can you run below and the output you are seeing?

** let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
if status == .Denied || status == .Restricted {
    // user previously denied, so tell them to fix that in settings
    return
}

// open it

var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard let addressBook: ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
    print(error?.takeRetainedValue())
    return
}

**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will give you that error.

```
if let addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil) {
    addressBook = addressBook.takeRetainedValue()
}
```

this must give you error that you are trying to change value of constant as addressBook is constant as you defined it with let.